# Feeding Blender an XML road file

Tags: python, xml, opengl, graphics, blender

My goal is to simulate traffic in a particular city. I'll be drawing cars using Blender and having them move about on lanes similar to a Manhattan configuration. All the information about the cars' relative position/orientation and speed at a given instant is determined by an XML file.

How do I read from this XML file in Blender so that the cars have the useful information about how to move on the road?

edit: Python is probably a good place to start. But do I actually have to parse strings? Or is there easy XML compatibility with Blender?

The XML I need to import basically looks like:

```
<sumo-netstate>
  <timestep time="0.00">
        <edge id="34403897">
            <lane id="34403897_0">
                <vehicle id="t0" pos="5.10" speed="0.00"/>
            </lane>
        </edge>
    </timestep>
    <timestep time="1.00">
        <edge id="-10745949#5">
            <lane id="-10745949#5_0">
                <vehicle id="t1" pos="5.10" speed="0.00"/>
            </lane>
        </edge>
        <edge id="34403897">
            <lane id="34403897_0">
                <vehicle id="t0" pos="6.54" speed="1.44"/>
            </lane>
        </edge>
    </timestep>
..
..
..
</sumo-netstate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be difficult if you use a xml dom parser of python.
Try below code, should work properly. I tested it in my PC.

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
from xml.dom.minidom import Node

domData = parse("XMLFile.xml")
lanes = domData.getElementsByTagName("lane")
for lane in lanes:
    #print lane id
    laneId = lane.getAttribute("id")
    print "LaneID: " + laneId

    #print vehicle id, position and speed
    vehicles = lane.getElementsByTagName("vehicle")
    for vehicle in vehicles:
        vehicleId = vehicle.getAttribute("id")
        vehiclePos = vehicle.getAttribute("pos")
        vehicleSpeed = vehicle.getAttribute("speed")
        print "\tVehicleID: " + vehicleId, "VehiclePos: " + vehiclePos, "VehicleSpeed: " + vehicleSpeed

domData.unlink()
```

This uses a minidom and parses the nodes of the xml document. You can get the node or element list by using getElemetsByTagName. Code is without null checks etc. so make sure you add them.

Happy Coding :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! How would I get Blender to use this?

Comment: @CyberShot, import blender script API in code above, `import bpy` and rest should work as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Blender is fully integrated with Python-3 and you all the modules from the Python standard library. Which includes several XML processors.